# How to create search function in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code:

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <!--Add class table-responsive for responsive table -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input size='14' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." name="searchValue">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" name='search' type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table mx-auto" id="'table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>More</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $pagination = new Pagination(7);

        $page_max = $pagination->getPageMax();



        $start = $pagination->getStart();

        if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
            $numberOfPages = $pagination->numberOfPages($database->getData("SELECT count(id) FROM customers"));
            $customers = $database->getDataAsArray("SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT $start, $page_max");
        }
        else{
            $searchValue = '%'. $_POST['searchValue'] . '%'; 
            $numberOfPages = $pagination->numberOfPages($database->getData("SELECT count(id) FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '$searchValue' "));
            $customers = $database->getDataAsArray("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '$searchValue' LIMIT $start, $page_max");
        }


        foreach($customers as $customer){
            $name = $customer ['name'];
            $surname = $customer['surname'];
            $email = $customer['email'];
            $phone = $customer['phone'];
            $company = $customer['company'];
            $id = $customer['id'];
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$name</td>
                    <td>$surname</td>
                    <td>$email</td>
                    <td>$phone</td>
                    <td>$company</td>
                    <td><a href='customerInfo.php?id=$id' class='btn btn-sm btn-info'><i class='fa fa-info'></i></a></td>



                  </tr>";
        }
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php

        echo $pagination->previous($numberOfPages);


        for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPages; $i++){
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page='. $i . '">'. $i. '</a></li>';
        }

        echo $pagination->next($numberOfPages);
        ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to search in my table, this works fine so far but when I search on A for example and I click my pagination page 1 it rebuilds the page with all te records from the database.

I tried to add a parameter to the url upon button click but upon creating this button with link the searchValue is still null.

This question is not about my sql query. It's about searching with pagination

Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You need to look in to using AJAX so the page does not refresh. There are ton of tutorials out there for that. But what's happening, is that your page reloads completely and runs the script from scratch.

Comment: `$searchValue` needs to be quoted in your SQL string, or better yet, bound to a prepared statement. Also, it should probably include some wildcard characters in order to be useful with `LIKE`.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun with that duplicate vote, and I have retracted it. However, I believe my previous comment is still something you should address, regardless of whether or not it is causing the issue you're asking about here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah you're right saw it right after posting but that doesn't solve this issue. Btw just fixed the wildcard & quoting error

Comment: What is this `getDataAsArray` function? It looks fundamentally flawed and a serious security liability.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.